# Mongoid : consistency strong for one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, consistency

I would like to configure Mongoid with the option "consistency: :eventual" except for one model when the consistency would have to be strong.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

For this model whenever you are making request, do it like this

```
Model.with(consistency: :strong).find(id)
```